# Is this piece supposed to be played by one person?

Tags: piano

Up until the 25th second of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oaX0EdbE4aI), player's left hand goes over a great distance on the keyboard. The right hand's keys are placed much closer to each other, and I don't have a problem playing this tune, so I'm only questioning the left hand's notes positioning.

Is that piece's left hand supposed to go over so many notes, or is there some trick to playing that part?

<sub>The composition in question is from Evangelion movie soundtrack, "Tranquility" by Shiro Sagisu.</sub>

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARDVTPVLhcM

Answer (score 3):

Yes, left hand arpeggiations are extremely common in the piano literature.

Valentina Lisitsa provides a good example:

That said, the pianist in the video you provided does appear to be using some awkward fingerings for his arpeggiation, possibly as a result of his not having a sustain pedal.

Comment: I fail to see what is so 'awkward' about the fingering s for the arpeggiations of the guy from this tranquility video.

Comment: All right, twice a thumb in a black key, but for people with relatively small hands (or for pieces with relatively wide intervals) that is quite acceptable.